# Continuous mapping between continous functions on a compact set

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

For metric spaces $(X, d_X)$ and $(Y, d_Y)$, let $C (X; Y) := \{ f : X \longrightarrow Y, f~\text{continuous} \}$. Let $g \in C ([0, 1]; [0, 1])$ and consider $(C([0, 1]; [0, 1]), || \cdot ||_\infty)$, the metric space of the continuous functions with the sup norm. Show that

(a) $G : C([0, 1]; [0, 1]) \longrightarrow C([0, 1]; [0, 1])$, $f \mapsto f \circ g$ is continuous;

(b) $G : C([0, 1]; [0, 1]) \longrightarrow C([0, 1]; [0, 1])$, $f \mapsto g \circ f$ is continuous.

Hint: Use that $g$ is uniformly continuous.

For (a), I tried to verify, following the standard definition of continuity, that $\forall \varepsilon > 0 \exists \delta > 0 : || f - h ||_\infty < \delta \Longrightarrow || G (f) - G (h) ||_\infty = || f \circ g - h \circ g ||_\infty < \varepsilon$, where $f, h \in C([0, 1]; [0, 1])$, but I'm getting nowhere.

I'm struggling with how $d$ and $|| \cdot ||_\infty$ are related between the different metric spaces. Does the sup norm in $(C([0, 1]; [0, 1]), || \cdot ||_\infty)$ imply that $d_X = d_Y = | \cdot |$? If so, what about the following example? Let $f (x) := 1$, $h (x) := 0$, and $g (x) = x$ for $x \in [0, 1]$, which are all continuous. Then,

$|| G (f) - G (h) ||_\infty = || f \circ g - h \circ g ||_\infty = \sup_{x \in [0, 1]} | f (g (x)) - h (g (x)) | = \sup_{x \in [0, 1]} | f (x) - h (x) | = | 1 - 0 | = 1.$

Hence, I cannot even pick $\varepsilon < 1$. I'm afraid I'm misreading the problem. I appreciate any clarification or hints.

Comment: In your "counterexample", $||f-h||_\infty =1$ so it's not as small as you want (see the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition)

Comment: Max, shouldn't I be allowed to pick any $\varepsilon > 0$, however small? For instance, wouldn't I argue that $1_{(0, \infty)} (x)$ is discontinuous in 0 because I won't find any $\delta > 0$ so that $|1 - 1_{(0, \infty)} (0)| = |1 - 0| < 1$?

Comment: But to pick $\epsilon$ however small you want, you need to allow $\delta$ to get very small too. The $\forall \epsilon $ means that you can choose it very small, but the $\exists \delta$ means that the associated $\delta$ should only exist: it can be terribly small

Comment: I'm sorry I don't see what is arguably obvious. However, no matter how small a $\delta > 0$ I choose, $|| f - h||_\infty$ will always be 1, and never anything smaller than 1. I understand that I must allow $\delta$ to be very small, but I don't see how this could make $\varepsilon$ smaller than 1.

Comment: I apologize for being imprecise in my first reply. I assume I should have said $|1_{(0, \infty)} (x) - 1_{(0, \infty)} (0)| = |1 - 0|$ for any $\delta > 0$ and any $0 < x < \delta$.

Comment: Incidentally, I don't want to say that my "counter-example" disproves the claim in the problem. I'm sure the claim is right and I'm wrong. The "counter-example" was just to illustrate how I tried to approach the problem and how I got stuck. Regardless of the "counter-example," I don't get the initial problem solved.

Comment: I think you have a misunderstanding of the definition of continuity. I'll try to expand on this in an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've misunderstood what it means for a function between to metric spaces to be continuous.

Let's rewrite down the definition : let $(X,d_X)$, $(Y,d_Y)$ be two metric spaces and $f:X\to Y$ a function. Then $f$ is continuous at $x\in X$ if and only if: $$\forall \epsilon >0, \exists \delta >0, \forall y\in X, d_X(x,y) < \delta \implies d_Y(f(x),f(y)) < \epsilon$$

Now what does this mean in English ? Well given any small quantity that I want ($\epsilon$) there is a little ball around $x$ of nonzero size ($\delta$) such that any point in this little ball is sent by $f$ close to $f(x)$, as close as the small quantity initially chosen.

Essentially this means that if I want to ensure that $f(y)$ is close to $f(x)$, I can always pick a small enough ball around $x$ in which this will be the case for all $y$'s. A slogan would be "you can get arbitrarily close to $f(x)$ in $Y$ if you are willing to go arbitrarily close to $x$ in $X$".

The $\implies$ is probably the part that's bugging you (it does so to many students at first). You should read it as a "such that", i.e. $\forall \epsilon >0, \exists \delta >0, \forall y\in X$ such that $d_X(x,y) < \delta$, we have $d_Y(f(x),f(y)) < \epsilon$. This is exactly the same thing (perhaps that's what's troubling you ?) but it may help you to understand.

Now what does this mean in our context ? Here $X=Y= C([0,1], [0,1])$ and $d_X = d_Y= || - ||_\infty$. Let's first consider (a). What does it mean for $G$ to be continuous at $f\in C([0,1], [0,1])$ ? It means that if I want $h\circ g$ to be really close to $f\circ g$, then I can make that happen by choosing $h$ really close to $f$.

This is what's wrong with your example: you want $h\circ g$ to be really close to $f\circ g$ but you're not allowing $h$ to move, you're not allowing it to be really close to $f$: of course you're not going to manage to have $G(h)$ close to $G(f)$ if you're not making $h$ move close to $f$. There's the exact same thing for any metric space $(X,d)$ and the identity function $id_X: X\to X$: if $d(x,y) = 1$, then $d(id_X(x), id_X(y)) = 1$ and it can't be smaller than $\epsilon <1$. But if *I allow $y$ to move close to $x$* then I can make $id_X(y)$ close to $id_X(y)$.

Now I'll show you how to solve the (a) part to see a bit how it goes. I have $f\in C([0,1],[0,1])$, and $\epsilon>0$. I want to guarantee that $G(h)$ will be close to $G(f)$. As you've pointed out this can't be done for arbitrary $h$ so I have to make $h$ move. But notice that for $x\in [0,1]$, $|f(g(x)) - h(g(x))| = |f(y)-h(y)|$ for $y= g(x)$, and so $|f(g(x)) - h(g(x))| \leq \sup_{y\in [0,1]}|f(y)-h(y)| \leq ||f-h||_\infty$. This being true for arbitrary $x$, we get $||f\circ g - h\circ g||_\infty \leq ||f-h||_\infty$.

Hence if I choose $\delta = \epsilon$, then all the $h$'s close enough to $f$ (those at distance $<\delta$) will also satisfy that $G(h)$ is $\epsilon$-close to $G(f)$: $\forall h, ||f-h||_\infty < \delta \implies ||G(f)-G(h)||_\infty < \epsilon$. This proves that $G$ is continuous at $f$ (even better, we proved that $G$ is $1$-lipschitzian but this isn't asked in the exercise), for arbitrary $f$, hence $G$ is continuous.

The (b)-part is a bit trickier since you need to use Heine's theorem, i.e. any continuous $g:[0,1]\to [0,1]$ is uniformly continuous; but I hope that now you will see how it works (if needed I can also expand on it)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, Max! This is more help than I deserved. Summarizing your argument,

$$|| G (f) - G (h) ||_\infty = || f \circ g - h \circ g ||_\infty = \sup_{x \in [0, 1]} |f \circ g (x) - h \circ g (x)| \overset{(\ast)}{\le} \sup_{y \in [0, 1]} |f (y) - h (y)| = || f - h ||_\infty,$$

where ($\ast$) holds because $g([0, 1]) \subseteq [0, 1]$. Hence, $|| f - h ||_\infty < \delta \Longrightarrow || G (f) - G (h) || < \varepsilon$ for $\delta := \varepsilon$.

Comment: Yes, that's a good summary for the (a) part !

Comment: If you don't mind checking my argument for (b): Let $f, h \in C([0, 1]; [0, 1])$. Again,

$$|| H (f) - H (h) ||_\infty = || g \circ f - g \circ h ||_\infty = \sup_{x \in [0, 1]} |g \circ f (x) - g \circ h (x)| = \sup_{x \in [0, 1]} |g (f (x)) - g (h (x))|.$$

Comment: As $g$ is uniformly continuous, $\forall \varepsilon > 0 \, \exists \delta > 0 : \forall y, z \in [0, 1]: |y - z| < \delta \Longrightarrow |g (y) - g (z)| < \varepsilon$. In particular, with $y := f (x)$ und $z := h (x)$ there are $f, h$ so that $\sup_{x \in [0, 1]} |g (f (x)) - g (h (x))| < \varepsilon$ for $\sup_{x \in [0, 1]} |f (x) - h (x)| < \delta$.

Comment: Why "there are $f,h$" ? It should be "for all $f,h$ such that"

Comment: Thank you for helping again!---I think I got my mistake. I thought that given $\varepsilon > 0$, I pick some (small) $\delta > 0$ and then require that $|y - z| < \delta$. However, uniform continuity allows me well to pick a $\delta$ large enough for any $y, z$ so that $\delta > |y - z|$. Hence, I may also choose $\delta > \sup_{x \in [0, 1]} |f (x) - h (x)|$. Is this right?

Comment: No but your proof was correct except for the part where you say "there are" instead of "for all": you already have all the right ingredients and you can actually already conclude that it's "for all", so I don't know why you wrote "there are"

Comment: I was thinking that, given $\delta > 0$, $\sup_{x \in [0, 1]} |f (x) - h (x)| \ge |f (x) - h (x)|$ might be "too large" for $\delta$. (If I just pick $y, z$ from $[0, 1]$, I may choose these close to each other, whereas the supremum restricts my ability to choose. Hence the need to choose $f$ and $h$ instead.) Uniform continuity guarantees, however, that I can find an appropriate $\delta$. With my last reply I meant that the point is not to find some specific $\delta$ (and particularly a small one), but to just find some $\delta$.